# gitignore is ignoring vscode settings file

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a folder .vscode in the root directory of my project.

In my gitignore there is the following :

```
# IDE - VSCode
.vscode/*
!.vscode/settings.json
!.vscode/tasks.json
!.vscode/launch.json
!.vscode/extensions.json
```

but although this should NOT ignore settings.json, the file is ignore when I commit.

What is wrong in my pattern ?

Comment: Why don't you just *not* ignore .vscode, given that you then try to un-ignore the four files in it?

Comment: You could forcefully add the files and track them?

Comment: both solution are valid solution, but they do not explain why this settings ( that are supposed to work) do not work

Comment: Do you have `.vscode/` in the local or global `.gitignore` or in `.git/info/exclude`?

Comment: in  global .gitignore

Comment: I am fighting to make git ignore this file, as I don't want to have the vs settings of my the last team mate that worked on the project. and removing the '!' doesn't work (that does get ignored)